# Management tool for PouchDB

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

I am planning to use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) as embedded database for a Node.js application.

Is there any tools (possibly for Linux), to inspect the db, run queries, and modify documents? Something similar to [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) for MongoDB? Or similarly to one of the many management tool for SQLite databases?

I know that one solution might be to run a CouchDB server locally and activate the two-way synchronization between the two. But this quite cumbersome process.
I also found [PouchDB Inspector for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pouchdb-inspector/hbhhpaojmpfimakffndmpmpndcmonkfa) but it does not seems possible to load the database directory directly as one would do, for example, with an SQLite database.